# php creating an array based off keys of another array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Background: I have an array created by:

```
$order  = $_POST['order'];
```

The contents only have a single value per row:

```
[0] => 1
[1] => 4
[2] => 5
[3] => 2
[4] => 2
```

I am updating a database with this:

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($order); $i++)
{
$sql = "UPDATE catalog SET quantity=quantity - $order[$i]  WHERE item_number= $i +1";

$result = mysqli_query($connection,$sql) or
die("<b>Query Failed.</b><br>" . mysqli_error($connection));
}
```

But I would like to use SELECT to search for records in which I have updated. Of course the problem is I do not have a direct item number to reference since I used $i +1 to refer to it.

As you can see the (array)key+1 to each value is equal to the item_number. So I was hoping to create an array in which the following is true:

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($order); $i++)
{ 
if ($order[$i] > 0)
{
$itemNum[$i] = 1;
} else {
$itemNum[$i] = 0;
}
```

I am sure I am over thinking this but I just need to be able to set up a WHERE statement displaying only item_num records which were just updated.

Comment: Are you wanting the auto incremented index number?

Comment: You could use an auto generated time stamp in the database, then just select all records that are less than 5 seconds old, or so.

Comment: Yes since the item number in my data base was created with an auto incremented number, I thought that would be easiest.

Comment: Yeah, but how many people are going to be adding records? You might add one and increment the index, then someone else might, then you again...

Comment: You may need a "added by user" field, so you can filter out records added by other users.

Comment: understood so probably the best way would then be your option of using the auto generated time stamp. Since the call for the select statement is directly after it, I will be implementing joins later so this might be moot, but what is the best way to reference the time stamp in a WHERE clause?

Comment: The very best thing to do would be to ignore the auto incremented field altogether, and create an invoice number field. Then you'll select all records with that particular invoice number. Invoice number can be generated by something like:
username + date timestamp ( susiehomemaker_11_3_2018 )

Comment: Just so you know, your query is insecure/unstable.  You should be using prepared statements with placeholders because you are writing user-supplied input directly into your query.  If the idea of prepared statements is unattractive to you, you _could_ cast the numeric values as integers like this: `"UPDATE catalog SET quantity=quantity - " . (int)$order[$i] . " WHERE item_number= $i +1";`

Answer (score 0):

Make an array containing all the item_numbers you are updating.  Then, select those item_numbers.

```
$updated = [];
for ($i=0; $i<count($order); $i++)
{
  if ($order[$i] > 0) {
    $updated[] = $i + 1;
    $sql = "UPDATE catalog SET quantity=quantity - $order[$i]  WHERE item_number= $i +1";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection,$sql) or
       die("<b>Query Failed.</b><br>" . mysqli_error($connection));
  }
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM catalog WHERE item_number IN (" . implode(",", $updated) . ")";
```

What are you going to do if the order is for more quantity than are remaining in catalog?

Comment: Thank you for your help! I was planing on a message suggesting back order status.

Comment: The web page ( I assume ), should limit the order quantity based on inventory too, so nobody could order more than in stock. Of course, if the site is very popular, many people may order the same thing at the same time. Hopefully you're using a transactional database, so it will immediately know if an order cannot be completed.